# How to call OnChange when form opens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My code works except for when it opens, it does not display what is in the dropdown. When you select a value in the dropdown, it works perfectly. I want it to open with the table hidden and then when changed to something else have it display as it does. Could a call to onchange when the form opens work?

My code:

```
<table width="522" border="0" text-align="center">   
    <tr>
        <td width="124">Number of animals:</td>
        <td width="129"> 
           <select name="count" select id= "count" onchange="showRows(this)">
              <option value="00">00</option>
              <option value="01">01</option>
              <option value="02">02</option>
              <option value="03">03</option>
              <option value="04">04</option>
              <option value="05">05</option>
              <option value="06">06</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="404" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="mytab" >
    <tr class="tabletitle">
        <td width="16" class="invisible">00</td>
        <td width="16" align="right" class="tabletitle">#</td>
        <td width="73" align="center" class="tabletitle">Gender</td>
        <td width="60" align="center" class="tabletitle">ID Number</td>
        <td width="281" align="center" class="tabletitle">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="light" id=>
        <td align="right" class="invisible">01</td>
        <td align="right" class="count">1</td>
        <td class="white">
            <select name="gender1">
                <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="white"><input name="id_number1" type="text" id="id_number1" size="10" ></td>
        <td class="white"><input name="name1" type="text" id="name1" size="35" ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="light">
        <td align="right" class="invisible">02</td>
        <td align="right" class="count">2</td>
        <td class="white">
            <select name="gender2">
                <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="white">
          <input name="id_number2" type="text" id="id_number2" size="10" >
        </td>
        <td class="white"><input name="name2" type="text" id="name2" size="35" ></td>
    </tr>

<tr class="light">
    <td align="right" class="invisible">03</td>
    <td align="right" class="count">3</td>
    <td class="white"><select name="gender3">
        <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select></td>
    <td class="white"><input name="id_number3" type="text" id="id_number3" size="10" ></td>
    <td class="white"><input name="name3" type="text" id="name3" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
    <td align="right" class="invisible">04</td>
    <td align="right" class="count">4</td>
    <td class="white"><select name="gender4">
        <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select></td>
        <td class="white"><input name="id_number4" type="text" id="id_number4" size="10" ></td>
        <td class="white"><input name="name4" type="text" id="name4" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible"0>05</td>
<td align="right" class="count">5</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender5">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number5" type="text" id="id_number5" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="name5" type="text" id="name5" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible">06</td>
<td align="right" class="count">6</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender6">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number6" type="text" id="id_number6" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="nam6e" type="text" id="name6" size="35" ></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

CSS:

```
.white { 
    font-family:arial;
    padding:5px;
}

.tabletitle {
    font-family:arial;
    padding:5px;
}

.invisible {
    color:white;
}
.count {
    font-family:arial;
    color:#999;
    padding:5px;
```

}

Javascript:

```
function showRows(s){
    var t=s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
    var rows=document.getElementById('mytab').getElementsByTagName('tr'), i=0, r, c;
    while(r=rows[i++]){
        if(t=='12'){
            r.style.display=''
        } else{
            c=r.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            r.style.display=c<=t?'':'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply raise the change event. That triggers the same action as a manual change of the value would do. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Just warning you that your code is full of mistakes that can lead you to face many problems in the future. 1 - You have a table before `header` (everything must be inside body tag); 2 - You are closing a div after close your `</html> tag, etc... I suggest you to clean up and indent your code. It will help you a lot preventing future problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things ...

1. The table renders in some browsers, but the code as written will encounter problems.  An html file should begin with an opening `<html>` tag.
2. Preceeding the `<html>` tag should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` instructing the browser to read the document as HTML5.
3. Next the table should be moved into the `<body>` and a closing tag `</table>` attached to not co-mingle with the next table in your document.
4. Your document should end with `</body></html>`.  Remove the closing `</div>` tags after the closing `</html>` tag.
5. I added an `window.onload = hideTable` so that Javascript will call a function when the page is first loaded.
6. I added a `function hideTable()` to hide the table `mytabs`.
7. I added a line to display the table before the rows are displayed.

Have fun!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">


<style>
.white {How 
font-family:arial;
padding:5px;}

.tabletitle {
font-family:arial;
padding:5px;}
.invisible {
color:white;}
.count {
font-family:arial;
color:#999;
padding:5px;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showRows(s){

var t=s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
var rows=document.getElementById('mytab').getElementsByTagName('tr'), i=0, r, c;
    document.getElementById('mytab').style.display=''; // Display the table
    while(r=rows[i++]){
        if(t=='12'){r.style.display=''}
        else{
            c=r.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            r.style.display=c<=t?'':'none';
        }
    }
}

function hideTable(){
    document.getElementById('mytab').style.display='none';
}

window.onload = hideTable;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="522" border="0" text-align="center">   
<tr>
<td width="124">Number of animals:</td>
<td width="129"> <select name="count" select id= "count" onchange="showRows(this)">
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
</select>
</td>
</table>

<br>
<table width="404" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="mytab" >
<tr class="tabletitle">
<td width="16" class="invisible">00</td>
<td width="16" align="right" class="tabletitle">#</td>
<td width="73" align="center" class="tabletitle">Gender</td>
<td width="60" align="center" class="tabletitle">ID Number</td>
<td width="281" align="center" class="tabletitle">Name</td>
</tr>

<tr class="light" id=>
<td align="right" class="invisible">01</td>
<td align="right" class="count">1</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender1">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number1" type="text" id="id_number1" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="name1" type="text" id="name1" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible">02</td>
<td align="right" class="count">2</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender2">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number2" type="text" id="id_number2" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="name2" type="text" id="name2" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible">03</td>
<td align="right" class="count">3</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender3">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number3" type="text" id="id_number3" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="name3" type="text" id="name3" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible">04</td>
<td align="right" class="count">4</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender4">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number4" type="text" id="id_number4" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="name4" type="text" id="name4" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible"0>05</td>
<td align="right" class="count">5</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender5">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number5" type="text" id="id_number5" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="name5" type="text" id="name5" size="35" ></td>
</tr>

<tr class="light">
<td align="right" class="invisible">06</td>
<td align="right" class="count">6</td>
<td class="white"><select name="gender6">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option> 
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select></td>
<td class="white"><input name="id_number6" type="text" id="id_number6" size="10" ></td>
<td class="white"><input name="nam6e" type="text" id="name6" size="35" ></td>
</tr>


</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Dreamwalker!! This is exactly what I want to happen. Your detailed answer has helped me tremendously. I have made all the changes you suggest and because you stepped through each one with your explaination, I now understand it much better.

Comment: Can you mark it as an answer?  Check mark on left side.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the showRows function when the page is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  showRows(document.getElementById("count"));
}
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pcos3vxb/)